# Windbg TTD automation

Tags: debugging, windbg, postmortem-debugging

I'm wondering if there is any way to automate Windbg + Procdump to take 5 dumps with 60s interval for each dump when the underlying application passes a threshold.

I have made some automation with Procdump with this command:

```
procdump.exe -ma -n 5 -s 60 -m 800 33512
```

But I don't know if there is any way to activate TTD (Windbg Time Travel Debugging) for 15 mn when the application hit the 800 mo threshold.

My objective is to build a single .bat file that takes the PID, threshold, time between each dump, the number of dumps to take and to tell my script to activate or not the TTD.

Comment: I'm also interested by you question, did you get further ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.